# One or more modules in this project use a version of App Engine that does not support Java 8

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Google App Engine project in IntelliJ. I have been working on it for a while but suddenly I can't launch the local development server from IntelliJ anymore.

When I launch Intellij I get this message in Event log:

> Java language level not supported: One or more modules in this project use a version of App Engine that does not support Java 8.  Please click here to automatically change them to use the Java 7 language level.

If I try to launch the local server I get this error:

> Error running 'Google App Engine Standard Local Server'
>                       Error running Google App Engine Dev Server.
>                       
> Exception occurred : com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException
>                       
> Exception message : java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml

I can see from my version control system that `appengine-web.xml` or `build.gradle` have not changed.

If I run 'gradlew appenginerun' it works ok.

How can I see what modules are not supported on Java 8?

Comment: What runtime is specified in your appengine-web.xml (are they all `<runtime>java8</runtime>` ?.

Comment: Also, can you check to confirm that the language level is set to Java 8: Project Structure -> Project -> Project language level

Comment: runtime is <runtime>java8</runtime>
Project SDK is also 1.8

Comment: So I ran update on gcloud components. There was a new IntelliJ version, so I installed that and updated Google Cloud plugin. 

Java 8 support warning went away but local development app engine still fails to start.

Comment: When I hit 'Edit Configurations' from 'Select run/debug configurations', Artifact to deploy is empty. And there is nothing in the droplist.

Comment: There is an error on to bottom of that Edit Configurations page.

Error: Artifact to deploy isn't specified. If no artifacts are available, ensure the following: 1) An 'exploded-war' artifact is configured for your desired deployment. 2) The App Engine standard facet is applied to the corresponding module(s) you wish to run. You can use the menu action under 'Tools -> Google Cloud Tools -> Add App Engine support -> Google App Engine Standard'.

Comment: I imported the project again from gradle. Seems to work now.

Comment: Cool. if you run into any more issues, feel free to post a bug on our tracker: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/new

Comment: @rooste You can post the answer and mark this issue as solved. This might get you some points and help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported the project again from gradle. 
Seems to work now.